# This particular use of xtabular makes latex hang indefinitely

Tags: xtab

Running latex or pdflatex on the following example causes a hang up, i.e. latex/pdflatex never ends:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xtab}

\newcommand{\PBS}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}%
\newlength{\tmplength}%
% table definition that divides available space in n equally spaced columns
\newenvironment{TabularC}[1]%
{%
\setlength{\tmplength}{\linewidth/(#1)-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*(#1+1)/(#1)}%
\par\begin{xtabular*}{\linewidth}{*{#1}{|>{\PBS\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{\the\tmplength}}|}%
}%
{\end{xtabular*}\par}%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{TabularC}{1}
 \hline
 \begin{center}
 \begin{TabularC}{1}
  \hline
  bla\\\cline{1-1}
 \end{TabularC}
 \end{center}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{TabularC}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If I replace xtabular by tabular or don't use a nested table in the document then all is fine.
Does anyone know what causes this, or how to debug or workaround this?

Note that above example is a minimized version of the output produced by doxygen, see the related bug report here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732768.

Comment: I'm dubious about the possibility of nesting `xtabular*` environments.

Comment: The nesting seems to make it keep switching between vertical and horizontal mode indefinitely.